# handle null pointer exception in scala

Tags: scala

How to handle Null pointer exception in scala with out if else condition?

```scala
val x: String = "null"
val len=x.length
println(len)
```

getting java null pointer exception error as below,

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "x" is null

have to avoid if else condition to check the null value using isdefined.

Comment: There is a simple solution, don't use `null`. If you are calling a **Java** lib that returns `null`, then wrap that call using `Option`

Comment: Are you interfacing with some Java code? If not, you would most of the time not use `null` in the 1st place. Use `Option` to represent the possible absence of a value with `None` or `Some(...)`.

Comment: Note that your code is defining a string containing null as value but it isn't null. I guess it's a typo (quotes added by mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the quotes around `null` are a typo, the best thing to do is to replace the `null` with `""` as soon as possible.

```
val n: String = null
val x = Option(n).getOrElse("")
val len = x.length
println(len)
```

Failing that, here is how to test the length of a `String` that might be `null`.

```
val x: String = null
val len = Option(x).fold(0)(_.length)
println(len)
```